# Remove Last Newline from Output of writeClipboard Function in R

Tags: r, string, character, newline

I want to copy a character string output from R to the clipboard. For this, I can use the writeClipboard function as shown below:

```
writeClipboard("my_text")
```

For example, I can now paste this output to a TXT file using `Strg` + `v`. The output may look as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

As indicated by the red arrow, the output contains a newline at the end even though I have not specified this newline in my character string.

**How can I create an output that does not contain this last newline at the end of my character string?**

The final output should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for `writeClipboard`:
... will write a character vector as text or Unicode text with standard CR-LF line terminators.

Instead, you can use `writeLines` and setup a connection to `"clipboard"` like this

```
mytext = "Abcdefg"
writeLines(text = mytext, con = "clipboard", sep = "")
```

The connection to `"clipboard"` can also be utilized by other functions, such as `write.table` or `cat`, e.g. `cat(mytext, file = "clipboard")`.
Here is [the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html) on the possible `connections` you can use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for! I had to add `sep = ""` to make it work as I wanted though. I.e. `writeLines(text = mytext, con = "clipboard", sep = "")`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've updated my answer to include `sep = ""` that it doesn't make a new line. I also want to mention that you can use `cat(mytext, file = "clipboard")`

Comment: interesting that writeClipboard cannot handle this.